# Engine shuts off when car gets into heavy traffic in the hot sun, after riding 200+ miles [twice!], WHY?

Tags: engine, overheating, suzuki

I have recently traveled from New Jersey to California in my 2003 Suzuki XL7. 
~ 140,000 miles

Recently replaced the serpentine belt, tires, and brake pads. 
Car has been receiving oil changes every 3,000-4,000 miles.

Car has been recently used as a delivery vehicle, March-August. About 6,000-8,000 miles.

I drive this car very safely. I try to keep it under 3k RPM since it guzzles gas like a mofo.

The trip was great, for the most part. I was paranoid about the car breaking down at any minute since I had used it heavily as a delivery vehicle.

There were two issues. The car engine unexpectedly shut off twice, in identical conditions.

I had already been driving for most of the day. I did about 200-500 miles per day. This happened once while approaching Dallas, and again on the border of Texas and New Mexico. It was about 90+ degrees outside. And there was really slow, heavy traffic.

I would notice my check engine light would go on. The brake pedal would become stiff. I would notice that the engine was off, the gas pedal was not working, and my car was rolling forward in drive, but not responding.

Obviously, I tried to start the engine again.

The first turn of the key: chugchugchugchug [That noise the engine makes when you put in the key and turn]. Nothing. 
Second turn: chugchugchugchugVROOM - eureka, the car starts. I pray, and get to my destination.

I went to replace the battery. My old one was incredibly corroded and the voltage was low. I thought this would fix it.

The thing happened again. This time I had to attempt the engine restart twice with no effect, and it seemed to chugalug a bit longer than last time before restarting.

Anyway, the car still works well for short drives and medium drives of around 60-80 miles. But I have no clue what happened. What caused the engine failure?

Coolant levels were not full, but still well above the "needs replacement" mark.

Other issues:

A strange, light, metallic scraping sound when the car was driving around 2k RPMs. Coming from the front-left-driver side of the car, around the front left wheel? Noise went away when revving up to 3k RPMs.

This has since gone away and evolved into an extremely faint whirring noise when the car is cruising without any pressure applied to the gas. Whirring noise goes away when I hit the gas. Wheel bearing, or something?

Comment: Alternator going bad maybe?? Can’t say for sure it’s just a guess

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Mikhail, there's many things that could go wrong, what we really need are the error codes from the OBD port, that will help narrow it down. It could be a sensor, a pump, filter, ignition system failure and many more things.

Comment: @GdD well, I'm not sure if an error code was actually posted. I think it's just the "check engine" light that goes on when you put the key in the ignition and don't turn it on - when all of the lights kinda go on. but I will try to check. Are there any places that can check my error codes for free?